# Looping across varying subsets of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe in R that looks something like this:

```
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(~Word1, ~Word2, ~distance, ~speaker, ~session,
          "WordA", "WordX", 0.14, "JB", 1,
          "WordB", "WordY", 0.21, "JB", 1,
          "WordC", "WordZ", 0.47, "JB", 1,
          "WordX", "WordA", 0.23, "JB", 1,
          "WordY", "WordB", 0.78, "JB", 1,
          "WordZ", "WordC", 0.51, "JB", 1)
```

I want to create a list of elements with computations of the data that differ by distance. For example, I  have run the following computation on the data, with subset `distance < 1`:

```
df %>%
    filter(distance < 0.1) %>%
    group_by(speaker, session, Word1) %>%
    tally()     # for each item in Word1, how many times does Word2 have a distance <1?
```

I want to do this for varying distances from 0-1, increasing in increments of 0.001. Using [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641948/r-looping-function-in-increments-of-1), I have got this far:

```
threshold_list <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.01)  # create an empty list with 101 elements
thresholds <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.01)      # create a df with distance thresholds
 
for(t in 1:thresholds){
    threshold_list[[t]] <- filter(df, distance < t) %>% 
    group_by(speaker, session, Word1) %>% 
    tally() 
}
```

When I run this I get the error

> Error in threshold_list[[t]] <- filter(df, distance < t) %>%
> group_by(speaker,  :     more elements supplied than there are to
> replace  In addition: Warning message:  In 1:thresholds :    numerical
> expression has 101 elements: only the first used

I think it has something to do with a lack of match-up between the list `threshold_list` and df `thresholds`, but I'm new to loops and am a bit stuck with how to move forward!

Comment: Remove the `1:` in loop. Specifically, adjust `for(t in 1:thresholds)` to `for(t in thresholds)`. Or use `lapply`: `threshold_list <- lapply(thresholds, function(t) { ... })`.

Comment: Thank you. When I try this I get the error "Error in threshold_list[[t]] <- filter(distancedf, distance < t) %>% group_by(Speaker,  :   more elements supplied than there are to replace".

Comment: But then I tried the `lapply` suggestion and it worked - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand the functions you are trying to apply to these subsets but hopefully this logic for running a function over subsetted data holds.

So what I'm doing in my solution is using nesting to accomplish the subsetting.

[Hadley Wickham talks through this logic in the Nesting Chapter of R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html)

Essentially we are creating dataframes within a dataframe and applying a function to each of these data frames separately.

So in the following I've started with the example table you provided. I created a measure of distance that will allow you to group results based on the increment of 0.001. And then I nest the data on that new distance measure.
So here is where we create a data frame for each measure of distance cut

Then we can use purrr::map to apply the tally function to everything in each of these data frames.

I like this approach a little better than all the looping because the code ends up being cleaner and easier to reason about.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tribble(~Word1, ~Word2, ~distance, ~speaker, ~session,
              "WordA", "WordX", 0.14, "JB", 1,
              "WordA", "WordY", 0.14, "JB", 1,
              "WordB", "WordY", 0.21, "JB", 1,
              "WordC", "WordZ", 0.47, "JB", 1,
              "WordX", "WordA", 0.23, "JB", 1,
              "WordY", "WordB", 0.78, "JB", 1,
              "WordZ", "WordC", 0.51, "JB", 1)


df_2 <- df %>% 
        mutate(distance_cut = as.numeric(cut(distance, 
                                  breaks = c(seq(0, 1, by =  0.001)))) / 1000)

df_2 <- df_2 %>% 
        group_by(distance_cut) %>% 
        nest()


grouped_tally <- function(d) {
        d %>% 
                group_by(speaker, session, Word1) %>%  
                tally()
}

df_2 <- df_2 %>% 
        mutate(results = map(data, grouped_tally))

unnest(df_2, results)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm having some issues accessing the output, though - I suspect this might be something basic that I'm missing, but when I try to save the output as a dataframe (`new_df <- unnest(df_2, results)`) I can't view/see it - for some reason it doesn't appear in my Environment. So I can't tell you whether this works or not as I cannot access the output (aside from the first few lines of the tibble in my console when I run `unnest(df_2, results)`).

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure. When I run the above on a clean environment I'm getting the expected output. 

I'm using v1.0.2 of tidyr, could you let me know which version you're using.
I'm assuming here that the nesting and the mapped function is working as your getting some output, so possibly the unnest needs more information.

Comment: I have tidyr v1.1 - I just updated and the code above runs fine, in fact the output is just what I'm after. It seems to crash when I try it with my own data, which is obviously much bigger than the sample here. I try to read the output to a df and it seems to process it ok but nothing appears in my Environment.

Comment: Does it crash when reading to a df? Or when the nesting / purrr stuff is running? 

If its the reading we could try selecting only columns we care about, or really just de selecting the data column containing all the nested tibbles. This could have an impact on the memory used.

Comment: It's when reading to a df. I'll have a play around with it and see if I can reduce the size of the data a bit!